# Spring - Initialize field using other autowired field

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, autowired

I guess what is the best way to resolve the following issue

I have a service with some dependencies and a non-bean field which i need

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl{
 @Autowired
 OtherService otherService;

 @Autowired
 DaoImpl dao;

 Entity entity;
}
```

I need to initialize "entity" field using `dao.getDefault()` method , this is my approach

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl{
 @Autowired
 OtherService otherService;

 DaoImpl dao;

 Entity entity;

 @Autowired
 public ServiceImpl(DaoImpl dao){
  this.dao = dao;
  entity = dao.getDefault();
 }
}
```

It's a good practice to mix constructor-based and field-based dependency injection? I can't use `@PostConstruct` because I don't have access to spring configuration files to enable it. Thanks for all suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not good practice to combine constructor injection with field injection. In fact, also usage of field injection only is considered as bad practice. Just google "Constructor vs field injection".

So I recommend to use constructor injection for `otherService` also.

BTW1, Use `private` for all the fields

BTW2, `@PostConstruct` should work out of the box without additional configuration

BTW3, you are retrieving value from database in constructor. This is often considered as bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to initialize beans with Spring:

- Injection by constructor.
- Injection by setters.
- Injection with @Autowired.

Combining configuration styles is also possible with Spring annotations on Java class, such as:

```
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig // enable the @Autowired annotation
@ImportXml("classpath:mySpringConfigurationFile.xml")
public class MyConfig {

@Autowired
DaoImpl dao;

@Bean
public ServiceImpl myService() {
    // Inject the autowired dao from XML source file.
    return new ServiceImpl(dao);
}
```

}

You need at leat Spring 2.5 and Spring post processor configuration must be set:

```
<beans>
    ...
    <!-- JavaConfig post-processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your's advices

Comment: Tehre isn't class `ConfigurationPostProcessor` in recent versions of Spring. Spring 2.5 is ancient version and shouldn't be used. `@PostConstruct` is enabled with annotation support, which @cold_ice is obviously using: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

Comment: I agree with you Spring 2.5 is old. Other people may use it however and ConfigurationPostProcessor can be found in spring-javaconfig.jar. If you are using a recent version of Spring, you can ignore the last paragraph about java config post processor.